# Combine Javascript Functions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to combine the following javascript into one function. I believe this can be done with an array of id's instead of what i did. Suggestions are of course welcome.

So in my code i just copy/paste the code and change the ids: 
thumbnail1, primary1

It's a boostrap 4 page with jquery-3.4.1 LINK to page: https://tools.apotamiefsi.info/service.html#_

I am currently studying some js, But i am really new on this. Sorry for any mistakes that i may have made, its my first question here although i have read 1000 answers :P 
IF i knew how to use vars i would not ask :) As i said i have no clue about js.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="linkwed2" href="#img1" style="display: contents;"><main href="#img21" class="primary primary2" style="background-image: url(/images/products/wringers/wringer_730/Wringer.jpg)"></main></a>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="container thumbnails" style="display:contents;">
        <a class="selected thumbnail thumbnail2" data-ref="#img21" data-big="/images/products/wringers/wringer_730/Wringer.jpg" style="padding: 6px;">
            <div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(/images/products/wringers/wringers_thumbs/wringer_730/Wringer.jpg)"></div>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail2" data-ref="#img22" data-big="/images/products/wringers/wringer_730/Wringer2.jpg" style="padding: 6px;">
            <div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(images/products/wringers/wringers_thumbs/wringer_730/Wringer2.jpg)"></div>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail2" data-ref="#img23" data-big="/images/products/wringers/wringer_730/WringerSteady.jpg" style="padding: 6px;">
            <div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(/images/products/wringers/wringers_thumbs/wringer_730/WringerSteady.jpg)"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.thumbnail1').on('click', function() {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var newSelection = clicked.data('big');
    var $img = $('.primary1').css("background-image","url(" + newSelection + ") ");
    clicked.parent().find('.thumbnail1').removeClass('selected');
    clicked.addClass('selected');
    $('.primary1').empty().append($img.hide().fadeIn('slow'));
});
$('.thumbnail2').on('click', function() {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var newSelection = clicked.data('big');
    var $img = $('.primary2').css("background-image","url(" + newSelection + ") ");
    clicked.parent().find('.thumbnail2').removeClass('selected');
    clicked.addClass('selected');
    $('.primary2').empty().append($img.hide().fadeIn('slow'));
});
```

The code for the light-box which is irrelevant

**jquery:**

```
            $('.thumbnail1').on('click', function() {
  var clicked = $(this);
  var neaSelection = clicked.data('ref');
  linkwed.href = (neaSelection);
});

        $('.thumbnail2').on('click', function() {
  var clicked = $(this);
  var neaSelection2 = clicked.data('ref');
  linkwed2.href = (neaSelection2);
});
```

And so on, i have like 7 on one page.

I expect the result to be something like:
an array of ids that would be matched with the clicked 
image and then the above code without alternatives:

```
$('.ARRAY_ITEM').on('click', function() {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var newSelection = clicked.data('big');
    var $img = $('.ARRAY2_ITEM').css("background-image","url(" + newSelection + ") ");
    clicked.parent().find('.ARRAY_ITEM').removeClass('selected');
    clicked.addClass('selected');
    $('.ARRAY2_ITEM').empty().append($img.hide().fadeIn('slow'));
});
```

Comment: What about... using variables?

Comment: Instead of giving each element a unique class, just have them use the same class and it should work. If you provide your HTML we can assist you better.

Comment: What is the HTML? Might not even need a loop

Comment: Along with (some of) the HTML, can you describe what you're trying to do?  Looks like a single thumbnail click shows a larger image in a matching 'primary'.  But it appears to be 1-1 (thumb->primary) rather than many-1 (each thumb going to the same primary).   So the 'selected' class seems to have no benefit.

Comment: If i knew how to use vars i would not be asking :) Kindly!

If i use the same class the galleries do not separate.. i will add a link to the page as well

I added the HTML code. Its a simple gallery with thumbs that rotate a main image

Comment: So you suggest that the best way to do it, is how i did it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code/comments indicate a single "primary" image with a number of "thumbs" that update that image based on `data-big` attribute on each thumb.

Within the '.click' event, you can use `this` to refer to the thumb that was clicked, this gives you the new image url.

Giving each thumb the same class `thumb` and using `this` means you can write a single click handler.

Here's an example using text (from data- the same as your url) in a demonstrable form, showing all the concepts.  You'll need to make tweaks such as setting the primary img src= to the new url, but the concepts are the same.

I've also added a simple method to show which item is selected as that was also part of the original code.

```js
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    var newcontent = $(this).data("big");
    $(".primary").text(newcontent);
    $(".thumb.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

```css
.thumb { float:left; border: 1px solid #CCC; height:30px; cursor:pointer; }
.primary { clear:both; border: 1px solid blue; height: 60px; }
.selected { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='thumb' data-big='THUMB1'>thumb1</div>
<div class='thumb' data-big='THUMB2'>thumb2</div>
<div class='thumb' data-big='THUMB3'>thumb3</div>
<div class='thumb' data-big='THUMB4'>thumb4</div>
<div class='primary'>
  PRIMARY
</div>
```

Comment: I have not tested yet but it seems like this would be work if one gallery existed. Could you tell me if this is the code to run 4 different galleries on one page? Check the link :) I will test this code

Comment: You can add give each `.primary` a separate class and add as a `data-primary` attribute to link the thumb to the primary.  Then the only change would be `$("." + $(this).data("primary")).text(newContent)`

Comment: Or, my preference, but it depends on where you thumbs/primary are located on the page you can wrap each thumb+primary in a wrapping div and use `$(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".primary")` (could be just `.row` in your case)

Comment: Please don't refer to third party sites ("check the link") as they will change over time making the question and answer useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="container thumbnails" style="display:contents;">
        <a class="selected thumbnail thumbnail2 main-thumb" data-ref="#img21"
             data-big="/images/products/wringers/wringer_730/Wringer.jpg" style="padding: 6px;">
            <div class="thumbnail-image"
                     style="background-image: url('https://www.edustoke.com/images/login-image.png')"></div>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail2 main-thumb" data-ref="#img22" data-big="/images/products/wringers/wringer_730/Wringer2.jpg"
             style="padding: 6px;">
            <div class="thumbnail-image"
                     style="background-image: url('https://www.edustoke.com/images/login-image.png')"></div>
        </a>
        <a class="thumbnail2 main-thumb" data-ref="#img23"
             data-big="/images/products/wringers/wringer_730/WringerSteady.jpg" style="padding: 6px;">
            <div class="thumbnail-image"
                     style="background-image: url('https://www.edustoke.com/images/login-image.png')"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.main-thumb').on('click', function () {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var newSelection = clicked.data('big');
    var $img = clicked.css("background-image", "url(" + newSelection + ") ");
    $(clicked).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(clicked).empty().append($img.hide().fadeIn('slow'));
});
```

Comment: Please check the provided link to the page. The provided code works as intended. I want to reduce the number of functions.

Comment: @ΣτάθηςΔρακίδης That is what he provided, by adding a common class you are able to apply the function to all of the elements...